# Sitecore role hierarchy

Tags: asp.net, security, hierarchy, sitecore, role

Is there any way to implement role hierarchy in 5.2/5.3 sitecore?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, 5.3 has support for roles in roles :).
But not in the UI. Have a look at /sitecore/admin/dbbrowser.aspx and switch to the Security database. The role items have a role-in-role field. You can add roles by adding IDs, pipe(|) seperated.